# Странное поведение setjmp и longjmp

Tags: linux, c

Есть следующий код:

```
jmp_buf jmp;

void func(){
    int temp;
    alarm(2);
    printf("Call\n");
    scanf("%d", &temp);
}

void func2(){
    siglongjmp(jmp, 1);
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGALRM, func2);
    setjmp(jmp);

    func();
    return 0;
}
```

По моей логике, должна каждые две секунды вызываться функция `func()`, выводя сообщение `Call` и предлагая ввести значение переменной. Но на деле, она вызывается только два раза - один раз при старте программы и второй через две секунды. В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в `setjmp(jmp);`. Нужен `sigsetjmp(jmp, 1);`. То, как код написан, в явном виде запрещено (сорри за английскую цитату):

> the env argument to setjmp() may
>        not be passed to siglongjmp()

Answer (score 0):

если мне память не изменяет, каждый раз в функции нужно опять активировать сигнал

Comment: Что понимается под активировать и в какой функции?

Comment: в вызываемой по сигналу func2 добавить signal(SIGALRM, func2);Когда сигнал обрабатывает, больше на него нет реакции

Comment: Не, не помогает.